# Error 2147942402 (0x80070002) trying to execute a command from WSL Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wsl-2, windows-terminal

Trying to create a shell script that, from a Windows Terminal running WSL Ubuntu, opens 1 new tab with 3 split windows and executes some commands on them.

This is working so far:

```
cmd.exe /c "wt.exe" \
 -w 0 nt -p Ubuntu --title "Panel 1" \; \
 -w 0 sp -H -p Ubuntu --title "Panel 2" \; \
 -w 0 mf up \; \
 -w 0 sp -V -p Ubuntu --title "Panel 3" \; \
 -w 0 mf left
```

This way I get the three working panels in a new tab, 2 on top, and 1 in the bottom.
When I try to execute commands on them, for example:

```
cmd.exe /c "wt.exe" -w 0 echo "Test"
```

I get the error, in a new tab:

```
[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) starting "echo Test"]
```

Running only `echo test` results on it running in my main tab.

I tried different things and searched around, but couldn't find the root cause.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? looks like you trying to execute commands simultaneously in several panes. WT can't do this - there is an issue about it, but they never release cool stuff quickly.
You can run a command during pane creation, but not after
`cmd.exe /c "wt.exe" \
 -w 0 nt -p Ubuntu --title "Panel 1" cmd /k echo Test \; \
 -w 0 sp -H -p Ubuntu --title "Panel 2" cmd /k echo Test \; \
 -w 0 mf up \; \
 -w 0 sp -V -p Ubuntu --title "Panel 3" cmd /k echo Test \; \
 -w 0 mf left`
I recommend using Tmux for stuff like this. WT is pretty, but not comfortable at all yet.